# Bash; edit file in root on ssh with sed command

Tags: bash, file, ssh, sed, replace

I would to replace a string with `sed` command in ssh from local to remote.

The file is **/data/PGSQL9.x/postgresql.conf** and I would like to change the string `listen_addresses = '*'` to `listen_addresses = 'localhost'`

I have to be root, so I do this :

`ssh root@myRemoteAddr 's,listen_addresses = '\''\*'\'',listen_addresses = '\''localhost'\'',g' /data/PGSQL9.x/postgresql.conf`

And I have this message : 
``` sed -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated ``s' command ```

And when I use `"/data/PGSQL9.x/postgresql.conf"` I have the same message.

Comment: Huh? The `ssh` command you posted doesn't call `sed` at all.

Comment: Also, note that in general, passing your remote command as separate arguments to `ssh` rather than a single string is a bad idea. ssh just combines them into a string in a manner equivalent to `sh -c "$*"`, so you lose information about where individual arguments start and end and how they were quoted.

Comment: Short form: `ssh root@myRemoteAddr 'bash -s' <<'EOF'`, put your code on separate lines, and end with `EOF`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not the same question ...
I had errors when I have tried the answer of the other question.

But using " neither ' it works, thank you :)

Comment: I didn't say either of those *would* work. Regardless -- please [edit] the question to show *how* you tried to apply to accepted answer of the other question, and exactly how it fails. It wouldn't hurt to show the successfully-tested local command you're trying to remotely invoke.

Comment: And once again, your `ssh` command *doesn't even invoke `sed` at all*, so it can't possibly be generating the `sed`-specific error message you include in the question -- meaning the ssh command in the question is different from the ssh command you're actually running. We ask that questions provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code *that actually generates the exact error you're asking about* when run by someone else. Bugs that prevent code from being tested mean that we can't reproduce your problem, and can't reproduce your answer.